# Error refreshing ElastiCache in Ec2.py when running Ansible playbooks

Tags: ansible, amazon-elasticache, ansible-inventory

For the past few days I am getting the following error when running ansible playbooks using the AWS cloud modules or when directly running the ec2.py file with the --refresh-cache command from my local machine:

```
ap:~ ap$ /ansible/inventory/ec2.py --refresh-cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ansible/inventory/ec2.py", line 1510, in <module>
    Ec2Inventory()
  File "/ansible/inventory/ec2.py", line 186, in __init__
    self.do_api_calls_update_cache()
  File "/ansible/inventory/ec2.py", line 492, in do_api_calls_update_cache
    self.get_elasticache_replication_groups_by_region(region)
  File "/ansible/inventory/ec2.py", line 722, in get_elasticache_replication_groups_by_region
    self.add_elasticache_replication_group(replication_group, region)
  File "/ansible/inventory/ec2.py", line 1198, in add_elasticache_replication_group
    dest = replication_group['NodeGroups'][0]['PrimaryEndpoint']['Address']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

This issue seems to go away when running from an Ec2 instance in the AWS account.

I have the latest EC2.py and EC2.ini files, Ansible version is 2.2.0.0, boto3 is installed and I do set the valid AWS credentials before running the playbook.

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the patch at https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/20190

```
 @@ -1194,13 +1194,14 @@ def add_elasticache_replication_group(self, replication_group, region):
          if not self.all_elasticache_replication_groups and replication_group['Status'] != 'available':
              return

 +        # Skip clusters we cannot address (e.g. private VPC subnet or clustered redis)
 +        if replication_group['NodeGroups'][0]['PrimaryEndpoint'] is None or \
 +           replication_group['NodeGroups'][0]['PrimaryEndpoint']['Address'] is None:
 +            return
 +
          # Select the best destination address (PrimaryEndpoint)
          dest = replication_group['NodeGroups'][0]['PrimaryEndpoint']['Address']

 -        if not dest:
 -            # Skip clusters we cannot address (e.g. private VPC subnet)
 -            return
 -
          # Add to index
          self.index[dest] = [region, replication_group['ReplicationGroupId']]
```

Comment: Ship it pls :-)